# How to mark a SalesOrder Picked then Packed using NetSuite SuiteTalk WebServices

Tags: netsuite

My objective is to respond to a picked event in an external system and mark the SalesOrder "Picked" in NetSuite and later respond to a pack event in an external system and mark the SalesOrder "Packed" in NetSuite.

I am using the code from the SuiteTalk sample application. I first get a copy of the existing ItemFulfillment record and then populate a new ItemFulfillment record.

The code works great when I respond to the pick event. Unfortunately, when I respond to the pack event, when I try to get a copy of the existing ItemFulfillment Record for the SalesOrder I get this error.

"You must have at least one valid line item for this transaction."

I assumed that NetSuite is complaining that there are no more line items to fulfill, so I  tried not adding any ItemFulfillmentItem(s) when I set the status to picked, but NetSuite didn't like that either.

The only documentation that I could find referenced a task Id, /app/accounting/transactions/itemshipmanager.nl?type=pack. This approach seemed credible because when I brought up Fiddler, this is the call that it made when I click the "Mark Packed" button in the UI. However, I would prefer not to introduce a different paradigm for talking to the NetSuite server.

I have found that NetSuite will let me go straight to the Pack state if I set shipStatus and shipStatusSpecified in the ItemFulfillment.

Can I move a SalesOrder through both the picked and packed states using only NetSuite SuiteTalk?

Comment: Could you post the XML that you are sending to the server?

Answer (score 2):

I was going about the problem incorrectly. Instead of adding items to a new packed item fulfillment, the correct approach is to find the existing ItemFulfillment and change its status to packed.

This is the search that finds an existing ItemFulfillment for a SalesOrder:

```
TransactionSearch xactionSearch = new TransactionSearch
{
   basic = new TransactionSearchBasic
   {
      type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField
      {
         @operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
         operatorSpecified = true,
         searchValue = new System.String[]
         {
            "_itemFulfillment"
         }
      },
      createdFrom = new SearchMultiSelectField
      {
         @operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
         operatorSpecified = true,
         searchValue = new RecordRef[1]
         {
             new RecordRef
             {
                internalId = salesOrderInternalId,
                type = RecordType.salesOrder,
                typeSpecified = true
             }
          }
       }
    }
};
```

This is the code that updates the ItemFulfillment:

```
ItemFulfillment update = new ItemFulfillment { internalId = existing.internalId, shipStatus = status, shipStatusSpecified = true };

WriteResponse res = _service.update(update);
```